# Creating nuget packages in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

In **Visual Studio 2017**, I have a C# class library that targets `netcoreapp2.0`. It is a `csproj` type project. I have installed **nuget v4.5**.

I would like to generate nuget packages from that library. In the project properties, I filled out the relevant package information. I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio) to set everything up.

When I click on the pack command for that project, the project gets rebuild but **no nupgk is generated**. Output is this:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: DuDiKiCommon, Configuration: Debug
>   Any CPU ------ 1>DuDiKiCommon ->
>   E:\repositories\DuDiKiCommon\DuDiKiCommon\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\DuDiKiCommon.dll
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

What might I be missing here?

Comment: Make sure you save your project after configuring the package properties. What is the complete output? After adding the path to nuget.exe to your PATH, make sure you restart Visual Studio.

Comment: @RamiA. Yes I have done all that. Updated the question to include the output I get.

Comment: Could you make sure your project type is Class Library(.NET Core) not test project or ASP.NET Core project? And could you reproduce this issue on the new Class Library(.NET Core) project? If not, please share more info about your project, or you can share us a test sample project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dotnet pack -c Release` or (in the developer command prompt) `msbuild /restore /t:Pack /p:Configuration=Release` to trigger the .nupkg generation.

You do not need nuget.exe for that.

Int this specific case, the dependency on `xunit` marks the project as test project which are not packable by default.

Use the `xunit.extensibility.core` package instead to ship helper logic or set this in the `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1520) for more details.

Comment: `dotnet pack -c Release` is also not generating any .nupkg. With the `msbuild` command, I get the following error (unfortunatly in german): `error MSB4057: Das Ziel "Release" ist im Projekt nicht
vorhanden.`

Comment: in the project directory? you could also pass the csproj file as argument as well.

Comment: Yes, I am inside the root dir where the csproj is. Also, here is a bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0 directory with the compiled sources.

Comment: omg I'm sorry I wrote release in the wrong place.. the target is "Pack" the configuration property is Release (updated answer). the "dotnet pack" command should work as well though

Comment: It does the same: Output says project gets compiled, but no packages are generated whatsoever.

Comment: is it a web project (asp.net core web sdk) or does it depend on any testing library? that would make it non-packable by default

Comment: Yes, it contains a reference to `xunit`. But I can pack it with a .nuspec file and run `nuget pack .nuspec`. What confuses me most is the fact that there is no error message or anything, it just refuses to generate the package.

Comment: Test projects aren't packable by default, see updated answer.

Comment: In my case my project was a netstandard2.0 class library. I also needed to add   `<PropertyGroup>
  <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>  
</PropertyGroup>` before it would create `.nupkg`